# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load login.component.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

I tried to access a custom built html using templateUrl in Angular2.

Here is my login.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login' ,
    templateUrl : './login.component.html' 
})

export class loginComponent{

}
```

Here is my login.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username">
    <input type="text" placeholder="password">
    <button>Login</button>
</div>
```

My directory structure has both the login.component.ts and login.component.html both in the same location.

When I compile this code I am getting an error stating

> localhost:8081/login.component.html not found 404
>
> Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load login.component.html ;
>   Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load
>   login.component.html undefined

Comment: Is `login.component.html` at root level? You're getting a 404, meaning it can't find the page at `localhost:8081/login.component.html`.

Comment: it is under a subdirectory called /login/login.component.html

Comment: i even tried to give the 
templateUrl : './../login/login.component.html'
still getting the same error

Comment: Are u using webpack or SystemJS ?

Comment: i am using webpack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need config your app to using relative url

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    //... other options
  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

import {Component} from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,    // fully resolved filename; defined at module load time
    selector: 'login' ,
    templateUrl : './login.component.html' 
})

export class loginComponent{

}
```

> The key lesson is to set the moduleId : module.id in the @Component
> decorator! Without the moduleId setting, Angular will look for our
> files in paths relative to the application root.
>
> And don’t forget the "module": "commonjs" in your tsconfig.json.
>
> The beauty of this
> component-relative-path solution is that we can (1) easily repackage
> our components and (2) easily reuse components… all without changing
> the @Component metadata.

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html

Comment: i am using webpack so i cannot use the moduleID

Comment: did you try all methods in the above article

Answer (score 3):

For developers using Webpack and facing this problem.

I resolved this issue by replacing:

```
loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader?keepUrl=true']
```

To:

```
loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
```

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Solved this issue by using

```
require('./login.component.html')
```

under my templateurl.

Comment: How? I get "template must be a string. Value could not be determined statically"

Comment: @Wagner: it may be worth searching the site for questions featuring that error. This post was originally written by skid, and they have not logged into the site for more than a year, so you probably won't get an answer from them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this type of errors comes because of the Angular could not find the specified path. I have solved this issue by changing the html file path in my templateUrl in @Component.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
template: require('./login.component.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your component using require()

for. e.g.
template: require('./details.component.html')